# How to fix the exception : ZenjectException: Unable to resolve type 'A' while building object with type 'B'. Object graph: B

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, zenject

I'm trying to load a prefab during runtime in one particular moment at my state machine. But I get this exception in runtime. All the scenes are validate with the Ctrl Left+Maj Left+V shortcut.

## The context of the problem

My state machine is bind into the project context :

```cpp
using Zenject;

namespace AVF.StateMachine
{
    /**
     *  @class AVFStateMachineInstaller
     *  Class used to represent the installer of the state machine
     */
    public class AVFStateMachineInstaller : MonoInstaller<AVFStateMachineInstaller>
    {
        /**
         *  Install the bindings between the objects
         */
        public override void InstallBindings()
        {
            // Global factory
            Container.Bind<AVFStateFactory>().AsSingle();

            // States factories
            Container.BindFactory<AVFInitState, AVFInitState.Factory>().WhenInjectedInto<AVFStateFactory>();
            Container.BindFactory<AVFLoginState, AVFLoginState.Factory>().WhenInjectedInto<AVFStateFactory>();
            Container.BindFactory<AVFSelectJobState, AVFSelectJobState.Factory>().WhenInjectedInto<AVFStateFactory>();
        }
    }
}
```

The state are create with a function CreateState in the AVFFactory class. No problem of creating states and navigate between them when I want. Except when I try to load a prefab who contains a game object context. So, I understand that all the managing of the state machine exist into the project context only.

I put, in the installer of the scene context, the bind of the factories of my prefabs :

```cpp
using UnityEngine;
using Zenject;
using AVF.StateMachine;

public class AVFSceneHubInstaller : MonoInstaller<AVFSceneHubInstaller>
{
    [SerializeField]
    GameObject mPrefabWeldingPedestal;
    [SerializeField]
    GameObject mPrefabSandboxPedestal;

    public override void InstallBindings()
    {
        Container.BindFactory<AVFSandboxPedestal, AVFSandboxPedestal.Factory>().FromSubContainerResolve().ByNewPrefab(mPrefabSandboxPedestal).WhenInjectedInto<AVFSelectJobState>();
        Container.BindFactory<AVFWeldingPedestal, AVFWeldingPedestal.Factory>().FromSubContainerResolve().ByNewPrefab(mPrefabWeldingPedestal).WhenInjectedInto<AVFSelectJobState>();
    }
}
```

My prefab contains a game object context with a installer :

```cpp
using UnityEngine;
using Zenject;

public class AVFSandboxPedestalInstaller : MonoInstaller
{
    [SerializeField]
    private GameObject mPrefab;
    [SerializeField]
    private GameObject mAttachObject;

    public override void InstallBindings()
    {
        Container.BindInterfacesAndSelfTo<AVFSandboxPedestal>()
            .FromComponentInNewPrefab(mPrefab)
            .UnderTransform(mAttachObject.transform)
            .AsSingle();
    }
}
```

And a component for using the object with the factory :

```cpp
using UnityEngine;
using VRTK;
using Zenject;

public class AVFSandboxPedestal : VRTK_InteractableObject
{
    public void Start()
    {
        Debug.LogWarning("HELLO SANDBOX");
    }

    public override void OnInteractableObjectUsed(InteractableObjectEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnInteractableObjectUsed(e);

        Debug.LogWarning(gameObject.name + "USED");
    }

    public class Factory : Factory<AVFSandboxPedestal>
    {
    }
}
```

My state who need the instance of the factory is like that and it's when I want to create this object I reach the exception because it can't resolve the type AVFSandboxPedestal.Factory :

```cpp
using UnityEngine;
using Zenject;
using Mimbus.StateMachine;
using AVF.Context;

namespace AVF.StateMachine
{
    /**
     *  @class AVFSelectJobState
     *  Class used to represent the select job state of the application
     */
    public class AVFSelectJobState : MbStateEntity
    {
        // Class fields
        private readonly    AVFStateManager             mStateManager;              /**< The state manager */
        private readonly    AVFContext                  mContext;                   /**< Context of the application */
        private readonly    AVFHeadState                mHeadState;                 /**< Common state of all states and scenes */
        private readonly    AVFSandboxPedestal.Factory  mSandboxPedestalFactory;    /**<  */

        /**
         *  Constructor
         *  @param[in] pStateManager The state manager of the application
         *  @param[in] pContext The context of the application
         */
        public AVFSelectJobState(AVFStateManager pStateManager, AVFContext pContext, AVFHeadState pHeadState,
            AVFSandboxPedestal.Factory pSandboxPedestalFactory)
        {
            this.mStateManager = pStateManager;
            this.mContext = pContext;
            this.mHeadState = pHeadState;
            this.mSandboxPedestalFactory = pSandboxPedestalFactory;
        }

        /**
         *  Initialize this object
         */
        public override void Initialize()
        {
            Debug.Log("Select job state start");
            this.mSandboxPedestalFactory.Create();
        }
// Other lines of code .....
```

## What I already try

I think the problem is : I have my state machine and the state into the project context and my prefab in his own context. So, apparently, it can't work. (No?)

So I try to add a Zenject Binding component on my prefab, I add the AVFSandboxPedestal in it and add the project context in it too.
But it doesn't work.

I try to create a factory outside class AVFSandboxPedestal and bind it to the project context with the component Zenject Binding. (But I let a binding in a installer in the scene context at the scene time. Maybe it don't raise an error but it is one), to bind class AVFSandboxPedestal to the scene context.
But nothing seems to work. I'm out of solutions for that problem and reading the documentation over and over again don't help me right now.

NB : I don't want the actual prefab persist in all scenes just in the actual scene. But the state machine have to persist in all scenes.

NB : If you need more precisions. Just ask. ;)

Thanks ! :)